# Trying to add email field in ProfileFormType of FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to add the email field in the ProfileFormType of FOSUserBundle.

User entity looks like:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    protected $email;
    protected $emailCanonical;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        parent::setUsername($email);
        return parent::setEmail($email);
    }

    public function setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical)
    {
        parent::setUsernameCanonical($emailCanonical);
        return parent::setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical);
    }
}
```

Profile form type looks like:

```
namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        parent::__construct($class);
    }

    public function buildUserForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildUserForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->remove('username');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_profile';
    }
}
```

The service is:

```
app.profile.form.type:
      class: UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
      arguments: ["%fos_user.model.user.class%"]
      tags:
              - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_profile }
```

And in config I have added this lines:

```
profile:
        form:
            type: app_user_profile
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you expand on, "Nothing happens"? Can you post your template?

Comment: My login view looks like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652849/adding-new-email-translation-in-fosuserbundle